# transforming third order ODE into first order ODE in order to find a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE
$x'''(t)=t^2\sin(x'')+\cos(x)+1$,
i've got to convert it into a system of first order.

My first try is:

$z_0=x \\
 z_1=x'\\
z_2=x''$

then I get:

$z_0'=x'=z_1 \\ z_1'=x''=z_2 \\ z_2'=x'''=t^2\sin(z_2)+\cos(z_0)+1$,

but I can't transform it into a matrix with constant coefficient. I want to transform it in order to find a solution of this ODE. Or is there another way?

Comment: Your equation is nonlinear, why would you expect constant coefficients?

Comment: Your system seems fine to me. You can now solve it numerically by finite differences for example.

Comment: in the worksheet they tell us to do, I only know how to deal with constant matrices to solve ODEs like $x'=Ax+f(t)$

Comment: You can't. The equation is non-linear.